# Why I get No error exception by boost::unique<boost::shared_mutex>

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, locking

I'm using boost to solve a multi-threads problem. It gets some problems when I use boost::unique_lock as **WriteLock**.

I simplify the code as following:

```
void test() {
    try {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> _(mutex_);
        Sleep(20);
        printf("asdfasdf\n");
    } catch (boost::system::system_error &ex) {
        printf("boost::exception:%s\n", ex.what());
        printf("boost::exception:%d\n", ex.code().value());
    }catch (std::exception &ex) {
        printf("exception:%s\n", ex.what());
    }
}


int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread *> thread_pool;
        int max_thread=1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_thread; i++) {
        std::thread *t = new std::thread(test);
        thread_pool.push_back(t);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_pool.size(); i++) {
        thread_pool[i]->join();
    }
    getchar();
}
```

when the **max_thread** smaller than 200 (nearly), the program runs smoothly.

However, it get many exceptions when **max_thread** bigger than 200 (such as 1000),The result is like this:

```
.....
boost::exception:boost::lock_error: No error
boost::exception:0
boost::exception:boost::lock_error: No error
boost::exception:0
boost::exception:0
boost::exception:0
boost::exception:boost::lock_error: No error
boost::exception:0
boost::exception:boost::lock_error: No error
boost::exception:0
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
asdfasdf
......
```

My system is win10 with c++11 and boost_1.67

does anyone know why and how to solve it?

Comment: Mh im not familiar with the syntax of `_(mutex_);` when i try to compile i get an error that _mutex is not defined. As i would analyse it this line tries to create a variable `_` with construction argument `_mutex`?

Comment: oh,I'm sorry,you must add the definition: **boost::shared_mutex mutex_;**

Comment: Okay might be too late but i now compiled and run your example on linux and i can not reproduce your problem so it does not seem to be your implementation.

Comment: yeah, I get the problem in windows 2010. Thank you all the same.